# Insert DateTime from ASP.NET into Stored Proc

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert a datetime stamp from an asp.net application into a db, but i keep recieving an error ::

> The column "W_Date" cannot be modified
>   because it is either a computed column
>   or is the result of a UNION operator.

Can someone shed some light on this. Also, I automate the datetime in my asp in a label, then pull the text for the sql insert with the following code.

```
lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Is this correct?

Below is my stored Proc code:

```
@date date
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_Wiki(W_Title, C_ID, W_Date)
  VALUES (@title, @c_ID, GETDATE())
END
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like there's anything wrong with your ASP.NET code, assuming the W_Title is the correct column name.  Do you have enough control over the schema to see if W_Title is a computed column or not?

Also, it looks like you're  passing in "date" as a parameter to your proc, but you're not using it in the INSERT statement.  If W_Date is a computed column to always be the current date, you should remove the W_Date paramter in your insert statement.

Comment: thanks Lance, I just figured out I asked the dumbest question in the world. My date is automatically triggered from my stored proc when I use the GETDATE(), there is actually no need for me to be throwning it in my asp page or even the stored Proc for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of the column `W_Date` in table `tbl_Wiki`.  It's probably a computed column, which means you can't modify it.

You could use this query to check if a column is computed:

```
select  is_computed 
from    sys.columns 
where   object_id = object_id('tbl_Wiki') 
        and name = 'W_Date'
```

Example of a computed column:

```
create table Sample (a int, b int, c as sqrt(a*a+b+b))
```

Here, `c` is computed every time the row is retrieved.  You can't overrule the calculation by specifying a value during an `insert` or `update`.